# Why i cant rotate on axis with 3d cursor

Tags: modeling, scale

Im rotating on x axis. Pivot point and 3d cursor set. Rotation and scale are at 0 and 1. Yet the mesh cant rotate on x axis. I tried to apply rotation scale but it rotate some different angle.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have "delta transforms":

[image]

Set these rotations to zero to fix the issue.

Comment: Well Thanks. may i know where this delta transform came from. What is delta transform?

Comment: No way to know why you have these transforms in your file. They are additional transforms apply upon "classical" transforms. A possible usage is to apply the same animation to several objects and each of them has different delta transforms... so for instance they are shifted or rotated differently.